# How do I query a table to give the number of instances of an ID using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables Doctor and Appointment. I need to produce a list of doctor IDs with the number of appointments made for each doctor with one or more appointments.

So far I have but I can't figure out how to get it to do what I want :

```
SELECT 
    doctor.doctor_id, 
    appointment.doctor_id 
FROM doctor, 
    appointment 
WHERE doctor.doctor_id =     appointment.doctor_id;

SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT doctor_id) AS NumberOfAppointments 
FROM appointment 
where doctor_id="50";
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: First off you need to fix your [join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) . 1992 was a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN` TWO TABLES AND USE [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
SELECT doctor.doctor_id,
       appointment.doctor_id,
       COUNT(doctor_id) AS NumberOfAppointments

FROM doctor
LEFT JOIN appointment ON doctor.doctor_id = appointment.doctor_id GROUP BY doctor_id;
```

Comment: why do you need a distinct in the count function?

Comment: Removed.Course of the Group By .Thanks :)

Comment: also the table aliases are absent

Comment: There's no need for a join.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of `doctor_id` value that appear at least one time in the `appointments` table, with a count of rows with that doctor_id that appear in the `appointments` table, you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT a.doctor_id   AS doctor_id
     , SUM(1)        AS count_appointments
  FROM appointments a
 GROUP BY a.doctor_id
```

The key to getting the result is the addition of the `GROUP BY doctor_id` clause, which effectively collapses all of the rows for a given value of `doctor_id` into a single row, so we get back a distinct list of doctor_id.

The aggregate function `SUM(1)` basically returns a literal value of 1 for each row, and then adds up all the those values from each row with the same doctor_id, effectively giving us a count of the number of rows with that `doctor_id`.

**Note**: you could also use a `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(*)` in place of `SUM(1)`, those will return an equivalent result. You could use a `COUNT(expr)`, where `expr` is any expression that evaluates to a non-NULL value for every row to be included in the "count".

---

To also return doctor_id that have zero appointments, we'd use the `doctors` table as the driving table for an outer join operation (assuming doctor_id is unique in the doctors table.)

Something like this:

```
SELECT d.doctor_id        AS doctor_id
     , COUNT(a.doctor_id) AS count_appointments
  FROM doctors d
  LEFT
  JOIN appointments a
    ON a.doctor_id = d.doctor_id
 GROUP BY d.doctor_id
```

Again, the `GROUP BY` collapses all of the rows that have the same value for `doctor_id` into a single row, and the COUNT() aggregate operates on the group. The expression we use in the COUNT() function needs to be an expression that is not-NULL for each matching row in the appointments table, and is NULL for rows from doctors that didn't have a matching row.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
doctor.doctor_id, 
count(appointment.doctor_id)
FROM doctor, 
appointment 
WHERE doctor.doctor_id = appointment.doctor_id group by doctor.doctor_id;
```

You can use group by clause...

Comment: There's no need to do a join, and no call for the old school comma syntax for the join operator.

Comment: @spencer7593, if the OP used comma syntax then it's perfectly valid to do so in the answer. voting down because of that is a very narrow thinking.