# How to join Count(*) columns with another column in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table like this

The first table is the "Appointments" table with 'doctor_id' the second table is the "Doctors" table also with 'doctor_id'. The duplicate values from the appointments table represents how many appointment each doctor has. for example the doctor_id(50) has 6 appointments.

```
doctor_id(Appointments)   |  doctor_id(Doctors)
          50              |         50
          50              |         51
          50              |         52
          52              |         53
          50              |
          50              |
          52              |
          53              |
          50              |
```

Now, my question is how would I show this table below (ps excluding the doctor id '51)

```
doctor_id (Doctors) |  Count
        50          |    6
        52          |    2
        53          |    1
```

This what i have tried so far, i have managed to work out how many doctors have appointments
using :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM appointment 
WHERE doctor_id > 50
```

I have executed other queries as well but with no luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I query a table to give the number of instances of an ID using SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768988/how-do-i-query-a-table-to-give-the-number-of-instances-of-an-id-using-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `doctor_id` is unique in the `doctors` table...

```
SELECT d.doctor_id        AS doctor_id
     , COUNT(a.doctor_id) AS appointment_count
  FROM doctors d
  LEFT
  JOIN appointments a
    ON a.doctor_id = d.doctor_id
 GROUP BY d.doctor_id
```

To get the count by doctor_id, you need to `GROUP BY` the doctor_id. You don't have to include doctor_id in the SELECT list, but if you only return the `COUNT()`, you'd just get a list of counts:

```
 appointment_count
 -----------------
                 6
                 0
                 2
                 1
```

With no indication of which appointment_count goes with which doctor_id. So, the usual pattern is to include what you GROUP BY in the SELECT list.

In order to return the 0 count for doctor 51, we want an outer join to the appointments table, so the row from the doctors table is returned even when there is no match.

---

If you only want rows for doctors that have one or more appointments, then you can just query 
the appointments table. (This query won't return any "zero" count for a doctor.)

```
SELECT a.doctor_id
     , COUNT(1) AS appointment_count
  JOIN appointments a
 GROUP BY a.doctor_id
```

Again, the `GROUP BY` clause is necessary to get a count of rows for each distinct value of doctor_id. That effectively collapses the rows for each doctor_id into a single row. The aggregate function operates on the "group" of rows.

Comment: @user3360335: The first query in my answer was returning wrong result for a zero count, because it was using `COUNT(1)` rather than `COUNT(a.doctor_id)`. The original query would return 1 when it should return 0. This has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.doctor_id, COUNT(a.doctor_id) FROM doctors d
Join  appointment a 
d.doctor_id =a.doctor_id
WHERE d.doctor_id > 50
GROUP BY a.doctor_id
```

try this code and hope this works. I am grouping the doctors appointments by the id

Comment: thanks for your comment. i didnot notice the doctor 51 thing in the question

Comment: +1: It's not clear if OP wanted the zero count or not; the query of the original form against just the appointment table will give the non-zero counts just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Group By doctor_id for counting how many times each doctor_id repeats itself :

`SELECT doctor_id,COUNT(doctor_id) FROM appointment GROUP BY doctor_id`

Comment: This won't return a zero count for doctor_id = 51. To get that, we'd need the doctors table to be the driving table for a left outer join to the appointments table.

Comment: yeahh !! I didn't notice. Thank you !

Comment: +1: it's not clear if OP wanted the zero count or not; this query returns the specified result if zero counts are to be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information in the question this can be achieved using just the appointment table:

```
SELECT appointments.doctor_id, Count(appointments.doctor_id)
  FROM appointments
  GROUP BY appointments.doctor_id;
```

However as the question specifically asked about a JOIN the following code will work:

```
SELECT d.doctor_id, COUNT(a.doctor_id) AS appointment_count
  FROM doctors d
  JOIN appointments a
  ON a.doctor_id = d.doctor_id
  GROUP BY d.doctor_id;
```

A working sample is available at SQLFiddle: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4b975/15)